# django login users and display their instance and items in the database

Tags: python, django

I have couple of models and one of them is a foreign key to the user model that's extending django admin. I want to display what belongs to a user in their session upon login. I have defined this authentication that will check whether a particular user exist within the database and redirect them to their session with their instances.

```
  def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
       auth.login(request, user)
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/studentloggedin/')
```

Basically, Registration is the first model and a foreign key to Student model, while Student is also a foreign key to UserLog. UserLog is extending the default django admin. I've defined the loggedin session here to filter out details of the individual users upon login.

```
   def studentloggedin(request):
       registration = Registration.objects.all()
       students = Student.objects.filter(registration=registration)
       alluser = UserLog.objects.filter(student=students)
       context = {
         'registration': registration,
         'students': students,
         'alluser': alluser,

      }
      return render(request, "studentloggedin.html", context)
```

Here is the template rendering the information upon login.

```
<img
  {% for student in students %}

  src="{{ student.student_photo.url }}">

  <p>{{ student.previous_school }}</p>

  {% endfor %}
```

But I'm getting the below error:

ProgrammingError at /studentloggedin/

more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: Have you tried running a for loop on student.previous_school ? the error is implying that you are trying to shove multiple objects into a single obj

Answer (score 0):

I think your re doing something that already comes with django:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
   # Do something for authenticated users.
    ...
else:
  # Do something for anonymous users.
    ...
```

from here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

you can also use decorator @login_required